# Creating table from parquet files

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am facing an issue on my inserting data.
In fact, I read some csv's files in a dataFrame and store the dataFrame on HDFS like :

```
val data = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ",").csv("/path_to_csv//*.csv")
data.repartition($"year", $"month", $"day").write.partitionBy("year", "month", "day").mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ",").parquet ("/path/to/parquet")
```

Then I created an external on my stored parquet like :

```
create external table tab (col1 string, col2 string, col3 int)
partitioned by (year int,month int,day int) stored as parquet
LOCATION 'hdfs://path/to/parquet'
```

Till here it is OK! But when I do a request on my table :

```
select * from tab
```

I have no result.
Does anybody face this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey can you check two locations hadoop fs ls /path/to/parquet and ls /path/to/parquet. Want to check to see if your Spark cluster is placing the output file on your local FS instead of the hadoop FS; it shouldn't but just checking.

Comment: @afeldman
I checked.... my files are stored on hadoop FS.

Comment: Are you creating this table in spark or in hive? If it's hive you will have to do a add partition or msck repair before you can access the data